# Override Bootstrap 4 Colors in PyCharm Django Project - Error: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: django, npm, sass, bootstrap-4, pycharm

I am trying to import Bootstrap 4's bootstrap.scss file as described in [Bootstrap's theming documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/). My IDE is PyCharm. My ultimate goal is to override Bootstrap 4's colors by importing bootstrap and overriding certain aspects that I want.

The problem is, I can't seem to import `bootstrap.scss` into my `custom.scss` file relative to the `node_modules` directory in my project.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
learnsass
  - learnsass <-- main Django project files (ex: settings.py)
  - myapp
    - static
      - myapp
        - css
          - custom.scss      <-- file I'm trying to import bootstrap from
            - custom.css         <-- automatically generated from file watcher
            - custom.css.map     <-- automatically generated from file watcher
    - ...
  - node_modules
    - bootstrap
      - dist
      - js
      - scss
        - bootstrap.scss     <-- the bootstrap scss I'm trying to import in custom.scss
        - ...
    - jquery
    - popper.js
  - static
  - templates
  - venv
  - db.sqlite3
  - manage.py
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
```

#### custom.scss

My custom.scss file looks like this.

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #cccccc,
  "danger": #840383,
);
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

A terminal with the output message shows "Error: Can't find stylesheet to import."

```
cmd.exe /D /C call C:\Users\Jarad\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.cmd custom.scss:custom.css
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
5 │ @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  custom.scss 5:9  root stylesheet

Process finished with exit code 65
```

I've tried setting the `node_modules` root as "Resource Root" directory. I've even tried setting its subdirectories as "Resource Root" directories or "Sources Root", but no combination I tried worked.

In PyCharm, I have created a File Watcher so the scss gets compiled into custom.css automatically. These were my settings there. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

[image]

### I did find one solution that works (use full absolute path)

I noticed if I use the full absolute path on my Windows machine (seen below), it actually does work (the custom.css file gets generated with all Bootstrap css):

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #cccccc,
  "danger": #840383,
);
@import "C:/Users/Jarad/Documents/PyCharm/learnsass/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

But I'd really like to UNDERSTAND why it's not importing using relative / sass / scss common practices. I'm not looking for a quick-fix or anything hacky. Plus, full absolute URL import is a pretty breakable kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting the `Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.` is because I didn't realize a critical thing - Bootstrap `@imports` from within `custom.scss` are ***relative to*** where `custom.scss` exists within your project.

From [UX Planet](https://uxplanet.org/how-to-customize-bootstrap-b8078a011203):

> Notice: The Bootstrap @import paths are relative to the custom.scss,
>   and will vary depending on your project environment.

When you do `@import`, you need to define a path **from** custom.scss **to** the Bootstrap .scss location.

A few examples:

```
# custom.scss lives inside static/project/scss/
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

# custom.scss lives inside node_modules
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

# custom.scss lives inside the root of the project
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```